# How to cut some elements from the middle of the sequence?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is it possible using LINQ expression to skip some elements from the middle of the sequence? I want to Take N elements, then Skip M elements, then take the rest of the sequence. I know that I can write my own function for that but I wonder is it possible to do it using only built-in functions?

Comment: Yes, there is bult-in functions for this purpose.
`Skip()` and `Take()`. F.e: `mylist.Skip(25).Take(16).ToList();`

Comment: That will skip elements from the beginning of the sequence and I need to skip some elements in the middle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use the index:

```
sequence.Select((value, index) => new {value, index})
.Where(x => x.index < startOfRange || x.index > endOfRange)
.Select(x.value);
```

Or, even simpler: (can't believe I didn't think of that the first time)

```
sequence.Where((value, index) => index < startOfRange || index > endOfRange)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int n = 5;
int m = 10;
int k = n+m;
var seq = Enumerable.Range(100, 20).Where((p,i) => i<=n || i>= k)));

// the output is 100,101,102,103,104,105,115,116,117,118,119
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `Skip()` and `Take()`, you just have to use `Concat()` as well.

```
sequence.Take(N).Concat(sequence.Skip(N + M));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
myList.Where((o, i) => i <= startSkip || i >= endSkip);
```